# accessing external storage directory from xml

Tags: android, android-xml

Is there anyway of accessing the external storage directory/sd card/internal storage directly from an xml file? such as the manifest or a preferences.xml.

I do understand, I can put a path directly in it but would prefer not to hard code it and instead use a reference to the directory. I do know that storage can be accessed in a certain way in the manifest, but I can't recall what were the keywords to look for. Apparently it seems not a lot of people do it, I can access it programmatically, but since I have a preferences.xml file for a preferences screen I would prefer it to be static